# Installing a jquery plugin in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-plugins

Im look for someone with patience to help a beginner install a jquery plugin into wordpress.
ive looked though various tutorials but cant seem to wrap my head around it and cant get it working.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/23/jcapslide-a-jquery-image-caption-plugin/

above is a link to the 'plugin' im attempting to install..

if anyone can help me out here i would be very grateful :)

Comment: WordPress plugins and jQuery plugins aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

In template's folder, create a file named **functions.php** and add this:

```
function my_init_method() {
    wp_register_script('jCapSlide', 'http://tympanus.net/jCapSlide/jquery.capSlide.js');
}

add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
```

Try and give us a feedback =)

Comment: and will doign that just bring it up in my plugins page? or what is next ?

Comment: What 'plugins' page are you referring to? Are you developing a custom WordPress plugin?

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple way : Just add these scripts :
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tympanus.net/jCapSlide/jquery.capSlide.js"></script>
```

in header.php file (file in your template folder)
Good Luck !